# Confusing Declaration with a Swift Completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler, computed-properties

I was reading the textbook "iOS 14 Programming for Beginners" by Armad Sahar. There are codes below in a MapDataManager class which I was stuck for days.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class MapDataManager: DataManager {

fileprivate var items: [RestaurantItem] = []

var annotations: [RestaurantItem] {
    return items
}

func fetch(completion:(_ annotations:[RestaurantItem]) ->()){
    if items.count > 0 { items.removeAll() }
    for data in load(file: "MapLocations") {
        items.append(RestaurantItem(dict: data))
    }
    completion(items)
}

func currentRegion(latDelta: CLLocationDegrees, longDelta: CLLocationDegrees) -> MKCoordinateRegion {
    guard let item = items.first else {
            return MKCoordinateRegion()
        }
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)
        return MKCoordinateRegion(center: item.coordinate, span: span)
    }

}
```

My question is on the fetch function. According to my understanding, the fetch function is accepting another function as variable, which is named as `completion`, and I am supposed to declare the "type" of the function after the `:` after `completion`, which should be `([RestaurantItem]) -> ([RestaurantItem])` to me, because we try to input a `[RestaurantItem]` array and just copy and output a new `[RestaurantItem]` array.

But now it seems that `(_ annotations:[RestaurantItem]) -> ()` becomes the "type" of the completion function and the input variable type is `(_ annotations:[RestaurantItem])`, which does not look like a type to me at all. I thought a type could be `Int`, `String`, `[RestaurantItem]` etc., what exactly is type `_ annotations:[RestaurantItem]`???

And why is the returning parameter `Void ()`? Apparently the completion handler has the `return` keyword that returns an item of type `[RestaurantItem]`!!!

Please help... I am novice with Swift and I don't have friends around who could help me with that...

Bosco

Answer (score 1):

The parameter label `_ annotations:` is syntactic sugar.

It's Swift 2 legacy and the compiler is only interested in the actual type which is

```
([RestaurantItem]) -> ()
```

a closure with a parameter `[RestaurantItem]` and without a return type.

---

To make it clearer this is the closure written as function

```
func completion(_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) {
   // do something with the restaurant items
}
```

Comment: thanks! got it now, didnt know that legacy...!